# ElasticSearch dump full index to a csv file

Tags: elasticsearch, export-to-csv

Is it possible to easily `export whole index`(all stored fields) of an elasticsearch cluster in a `.csv` file(possibly out of the box)?

The alternative I can think is query the whole index and then convert the result... but I really don't like the idea of parsing a monstrous `json` since it contains some millions of documents!

Are there any other ways or ideas to achieve the export?

Comment: https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-csv

Comment: @KonstantinV.Salikhov looks good! I was hoping to not involve third party plugins, but this seems to cover my needs!

Comment: Actually I've never tried this, and there might be some performance problems

Comment: The `elasticsearch-csv` is not a productions olution in my opinion.

Comment: https://github.com/taraslayshchuk/es2csv (from a deleted answer from @taraslayshchuk )

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I'm the author of estab.

---

[estab](https://github.com/miku/estab) exports elasticsearch fields as tab separated values. If you do not have too many fields, it's easy to explicitly export them all. Internally estab uses the scan and scroll API.

Example:

Assume your index contains documents like:

```
{
    "name": "Kiwi",
    "genus": "Apteryx",
    "populations": [
        {"location": "North Island", "size": 2500},
        {"location": "Little Barrier Island", "size": 2000}
    ]
}
```

Then you can export a whole index via:

```
$ estab -f 'name genus populations.location populations.size'
Kiwi    Apteryx North Island|Little Barrier Island  2500|2000
```

Note that nested fields are not easily mapped into a tabular form. `estab` by default separates multiple values by `|` and you can refer to nested fields via usual dot notation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Scan and Scroll API](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/scan-scroll.html). Then you wouldn't have a monstrous JSON file to parse--you could do it in much smaller batches.

Comment: Link for "Scan and Scrall API" is dead. API is also deprecated. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/breaking_21_search_changes.html#_literal_search_type_scan_literal_deprecated